# String concatenation without libraries in C

Tags: c, struct, concatenation, c-strings, function-definition

I am having trouble concatenating strings in C without library function.
I tried the following:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct word {
  char *str;
  int wordSize;
};

void concat(struct word words[], int arraySize, int maxSize) { // word array, its size, and max size given
  char result[maxSize];
  int resultSize = 0;
  struct word tmp;

  for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    tmp = words[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < words[i].wordSize; j++,  resultSize++) {
      result[resultSize + j] = tmp.str[j];
    }
  }

  puts(result);
}
```

For example, if the struct array `words` contain `[{"he", 2}, {"ll", 2}, {"o", 1}]`, the `result` should be `hello`. However, this code prints `h�l�o` where the second and fourth letters are questionmark. Can anyone help me debug this?

Comment: `result[resultSize + j] = tmp.str[j];` is wrong, you are incrementing `j` and `resultSize` in each iteration, so you are jumping over every second index in `result`.

Comment: @mch I see. Thanks for that. That solved the problem.

Comment: @mmmdwldmm All answers except mine are bad and presented functions can invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it simple and the bugs will fix themselves. Don't mix up the position in the `result` buffer with the loop iterators. No need for temporary variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  char *str;
  int wordSize;
} word;

void concat(word words[], int arraySize, int maxSize) { 
  char result[maxSize];
  int count=0;
  
  for(int i=0; i<arraySize; i++)
  {
    for(int j=0; j<words[i].wordSize; j++)
    {
      result[count]= words[i].str[j];
      count++;
    }
  }
  result[count] = '\0';
  
  puts(result);
}

int main()
{
  word w[3] = { {"he", 2}, {"ll", 2}, {"o", 1} };
  concat(w, 3, 128);
}
```

Comment: I see I actually already solved it with the help of @mch's comment but looking at your code, it seems that my codes needed a lot of improvements anyway. Thanks so much for the tips.

Comment: you might want to check for `maxSIze` in the `concat()` loops

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt No, but perhaps at the beginning of the function. Since `result` is obviously a buffer large enough to hold `maxSize`.

Comment: what I meant is that there is no check if the added sizes of the single words exceed maxSize. Of course that could be done in a seperate loop too

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Ah I get it now, indeed such a check should be made somewhere. But these kind of artificial newbie programs tend to lack plenty in the ways of error handling overall :)

Answer (score 1):

In this for loop

```
for (int j = 0; j < words[i].wordSize; j++,  resultSize++) {
  result[resultSize + j] = tmp.str[j];
}
```

you are incrementing `resultSize` and `j` simultaneously while you need to increase only the variable `j` and after the loop increase the variable `resultSize` by `j`.

But in any case the function is wrong because there is no check that `resultSize` is less than `maxSize`.

And moreover the built string is not appended with the terminating zero `'\0'`. As a result this statement

```
puts(result);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

There is no need to create the variable length array

```
char result[maxSize];
```

just to output the concatenated string.

The function can be declared and defined the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct word {
  char *str;
  int wordSize;
};

void concat( const struct word words[], size_t arraySize, size_t maxSize )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < maxSize && j < arraySize; j++ )
    {
        for ( size_t k = 0; i < maxSize && k < words[j].wordSize; i++, k++ )
        {
            putchar( words[j].str[k] );
        }
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct word words[] =
    {
        { "he", 2 }, { "ll", 2 }, { "o", 1 }
    };
    const size_t arraySize = sizeof( words ) / sizeof( *words );
    
    concat( words, arraySize, 5 );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
hello
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems here. `result[resultSize + j]` means you are effectively skipping over half the characters in result. Secondly, if you copy the entire string, including the null character, `puts` will stop printing the result string at the end of the first word itself. So you need to skip copying the string terminator and put it in at the end of your whole concatenated string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct word {
  char *str;
  int wordSize;
};

void concat(struct word words[], int maxSize) { // word array and max size given
  char result[maxSize];
  int resultSize = 0;
  struct word tmp;

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    tmp = words[i];
    // Keep copying the words to result, one after the other
    // But drop the last NULL character
    for (int j = 0; j < (words[i].wordSize - 1); j++,  resultSize++) {      
      result[resultSize] = tmp.str[j]; 
    }
  }
  // Put the NULL character in after all words have been copied
  result[resultSize] = 0;
  puts(result);
}

struct word mywords[] = 
{
  { "TestWord", sizeof("TestWord")},
  { "TestWord2", sizeof("TestWord2")}
};

int main(void)
{
  concat(mywords, 100);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Big thanks. Sorry that I cannot accept both answers. I just selected the earlier one.